# Interpretation of Speaman Rank vs Kendall's Tau

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

## Main question

At work I am measuring the correlation of 2 R.Vs. When calculating the Spearman rho and Kendall's tau coefficients I get values of 0.78 and 0.52 respectively.

I am confused though as how to interpret this as these values are further apart than I would have expected (given they both measure association based upon rankings).  I feel like the Spearman rho value indicates a very strong relationship where as the Kendall's tau value indicates only a medium strength relationship.

My questions then:

- Are my interpretations/understanding correct (or is it normal for them to be this far apart)?
- If these are further apart than normally expected what scenarios or structure to the data could there be to cause such a difference between the measures?

(Unfortunately as its work data I can't share it :( )

### Appendix - Further details

The 2 R.V's in question are both time to event variables. The correlations are being calculated by fitting a Gumbel copula model using the Nelson-Aalen estimate for the survival distribution of each R.V.  From the copula parameter  we then estimate Kendall's Tau using a known identity and Spearman's Rho  by numerical integration.

Comment: In my experience, over multiple data sets, Spearman's rho has always been larger than Kendall's tau in absolute value.The bivariate relationship must be super-strong for Kendall's tau to approach +/-1.

Comment: "(given they both measure association based upon rankings)" - they do, but in distinctly different ways. As stans says, Kendall's tau is usually smaller. If you know enough about the joint distribution you can see how they're related.

Comment: e.g. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxByW.png)'s the correlations (s=Spearman, k=Kendall) for 10,000 bivariate samples of size 10 from a Gaussian copula ($\rho=0.6$). You can see that the Spearman correlation is usually larger in absolute size (tending to be below the red line in the right half, above it on the left side)

Comment: Thanks  @Glen_b  this (especially the plot) helps a lot !